# Substring from string with special emoticons, String.IndexOf returns -1

Tags: c#, string, unicode

I have a string with a special emoticon:

```
string test = "<textarea style='display:none;'>˃̣̣̥᷄⌓˂̣̣̥᷅  abcde";
```

And I want to get a substring of this string like below:

```
string sub = test.Substring(test.IndexOf(">"));
```

(because the first ">" of string "test" means the end of HTML code)

(The result I want is `˃̣̣̥᷄⌓˂̣̣̥᷅  abcde`)

However, the `Substring` method returns an error("StartIndex cannot be less than 0") which means there is no '>' in the string 'test.'

So I tested something like the below:

```
test.Contains(">");
```

It returns 'True.'

Here is my question: the `Contains` method says that the string 'test' contains '>' in it, but the `Substring` method doesn't work properly...

How can I get the right substring from the string 'test'?

Comment: I have removed the metro tag as this is more of a question about strings/substrings and shouldn't be dependant on application type

Comment: @TimSchmelter Something like `StartIndex cannot be less than 0` I guess.

Comment: [`IndexOf(String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx) performs a culture sensitive search whereas [`IndexOf(Char)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwb0bwyd.aspx) ignores the cultures. [`Contains(String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) also uses ordinal (cultures insensitive) comparison.

Comment: Note that you can simply use `test.IndexOf(">", StringComparison.Ordinal)`.

Comment: Yes~ I guess it is more proper title~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others already said, `IndexOf(">")` performans a culture sensitive search. That means you have to keep in mind that there exists characters that are basically a combination of different unicode characters.

Let's look at this part of your string: `;'>˃̣̣̥᷄⌓˂̣̣̥᷅`

It contains the following unicode characters:

```
SEMICOLON (U+003B) 
APOSTROPHE (U+0027) 
GREATER-THAN SIGN (U+003E) 
MODIFIER LETTER RIGHT ARROWHEAD (U+02C3) 
COMBINING DOT BELOW (U+0323) 
COMBINING DOT BELOW (U+0323) 
COMBINING RING BELOW (U+0325) 
COMBINING MACRON-ACUTE (U+1DC4) 
SEGMENT (U+2313) 
MODIFIER LETTER LEFT ARROWHEAD (U+02C2) 
COMBINING DOT BELOW (U+0323) 
COMBINING DOT BELOW (U+0323) 
COMBINING RING BELOW (U+0325) 
COMBINING GRAVE-MACRON (U+1DC5)
```

Note that while it contains a [`GREATER-THAN SIGN` (U+003E `>`)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/003E/index.htm) character, note that it is followed by a [`MODIFIER LETTER RIGHT ARROWHEAD` (U+02C3 `˃`)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/02C3/index.htm) character. This character is a so called [*spacing modifier letter*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacing_Modifier_Letters), which are used to change the meaning of the previous or following character.

This behaviour is quite similiar to the following characters (`COMBINING DOT BELOW`, `COMBINING RING BELOW`), which are [*combining diacritical marks*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks), but these are usually placed on top or below the character they modify (as you can see here:
`̣̣̥᷄⌓`, which is a `SEGMENT`, modified by two `DOT BELOW`, a `RING BELOW` and a `MACRON_ACUTE`.

So, if you take  combining characters into account (which `IndexOf(String)` does), then your string does not contain the string `>` (a single greater than sign).

To check for a single (not combined) character, you can use [`IndexOf('>')`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwb0bwyd.aspx) (using a `char` instead of a `string`):

> This method performs an ordinal (culture-insensitive) search, where a character is considered equivalent to another character only if their Unicode scalar values are the same.

or `test.IndexOf(">", StringComparison.Ordinal)`.

---

That being said, if you want to parse HTML, better use an HTML-parser like [Html Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/):

```
string html = "<textarea style='display:none;'>˃̣̣̥᷄⌓˂̣̣̥᷅  abcde</textarea>";
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
var value = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//textarea").InnerText;
```

`value` now contains `˃̣̣̥᷄⌓˂̣̣̥᷅  abcde`

Comment: Thank you for the most detailed explanation!
I tried your first solution (putting an option)

Comment: Thank you for the most detailed explanation!
I tried your first solution (putting an option), but the result is not what I wanted..because it becomes like this
(http://cfile22.uf.tistory.com/image/222F563C539D0FF72A700E)
Those letters are separated and becomes weird...

How can I solve this problem?

Deeply thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

use Single Quotes around your character test.

```
string sub = test.Substring(test.IndexOf('>'));
```

If you want to use "strings" instead of a 'c'har, you need to specify a stringComparison Type.

```
string test = "<textarea style='display:none;'>˃̣̣̥᷄⌓˂̣̣̥᷅  abcde"; 
string sub = test.Substring(test.IndexOf(">", StringComparison.Ordinal));
Console.WriteLine(test.IndexOf(">", StringComparison.Ordinal));
Console.WriteLine(sub);
```

The default behavior for `string.IndexOf(string s)` is to do a `StringComparison.CurrentCulture` culture sensitive Comparison.

[String.IndexOf Method (String) (System) @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx)

Comment: Definitely, it works,, but the result is not what I wanted as I mentioned in the comments above. Thank you for your answer!